Parsing url from buttons and confirmation messages using Telethon
There are buttons that immediately open the web application, and there are those that call a window with a confirmation of opening, how to sparse the url from it?
Example of a button that brings up a confirmation window
Example of a confirmation window
I couldn't find anything in the telethon docs that would help me out
link to the bot, for example

In Telethon v1, a Message has a list of list of .buttons. These are MessageButton and may have .url:
for row in message.buttons:
  for button in row:
    if button.url:
      ...  # use button.url

